# I want to find top 10 customer using def in python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find top 10 customers for each city in terms of their repayment amount by different products and by different time periods i.e. year or month. The user should be able to specify the product (Gold/Silver/Platinum) and time period (yearly or monthly) and the function should automatically take these inputs while identifying the top 10 customers.

So what I did:

1. create another dataset:

```
Cust_table_repayment=customer_repayment[['Customer','Age','City','Product','Limit','Company','Segment','Month','Amount']]
```

2. converted the month column to pd.to_datetime

```
Cust_table_repayment['Month']=pd.to_datetime(Cust_table_repayment['Month'])
```

3. created another variable in new dataset : monthly,yearly

```
Cust_table_repayment['monthly']=Cust_table_repayment['Month'].apply(lambda x:x.month)

Cust_table_repayment['yearly']=Cust_table_repayment['Month'].apply(lambda x:x.year)
```

4. Then created the function and this is the part where I'm stuck and facing problem:

```
def top10Customers(prod_cat,time_period):
    return Cust_table_repayment.loc[(Cust_table_repayment['Product']==prod_cat)&((Cust_table_repayment.monthly==time_period)|(Cust_table_repayment.yearly==time_period))].groupby(['Customer','Product','City','Month']).Amount.sum().reset_index().sort_values('Amount',ascending=False).head(10)
```

then I declared the input:

```
prod_cat=str(input("Please Enter Product either in Gold/Silver/Platinum: "))
time_period=input("Please Enter Time Period and time period should be in yearly/monthly: ")
```

then I stored that function in new dataset

```
Top_10_customer=top10Customers(prod_cat,time_period)
```

and called that dataset but getting no output

```
Top_10_customer
```

[image]

My expected output:  when I search yearly or monthly then it should display either monthly or yearly like this:

[image]

Please help!

Comment: It'll be easier for others to help if you provide some sample data which can reproduce your problem.

Comment: sir i forgot to add data,but sir is it still possible to add sample data,or screenshot  because i'm new to stackoverflow and missed some point

Comment: It'll be easier for others to reproduce your problem if you can provide sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the data type of input data and data type of each column in the given dataframe.

- The column "monthly" and "yearly" have data type "int"
- The input value has data type "str"
  So the comparison in module top10Customers doesn't work.

```
Cust_table_repayment = customer_repayment[['Customer','Age','City'
                                           ,'Product','Limit','Company'
                                           ,'Segment','Month','Amount']].copy()

# check the date format, if it is "YYYY-MM-DD", put yearfirst=True
Cust_table_repayment['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(Cust_table_repayment['Month'])

# use Cust_table_repayment["monthly"].dtypes to check the type, which is "int"
Cust_table_repayment['monthly'] = Cust_table_repayment['Month'].apply(lambda x : x.month)

# use Cust_table_repayment["yearly"].dtypes to check the type, which is "int"
Cust_table_repayment['yearly'] = Cust_table_repayment['Month'].apply(lambda x:x.year)


#### Solution 
# if you want to convert the monthly and yearly to string
Cust_table_repayment["monthly"] = Cust_table_repayment["Month"].dt.month.astype(str)

# else, convert input to appropriate type
time_period = int(input("Please Enter Time Period and time period should be in yearly/monthly: "))

# and do a little preprocessing for prod_cat 
prod_cat = str(input("Please Enter Product either in Gold/Silver/Platinum:")).lower().strip()

def top10Customers(prod_cat,time_period):
    return Cust_table_repayment.loc[(Cust_table_repayment['Product'].str.lower()==prod_cat)
                                    &(
                                        (Cust_table_repayment.monthly==time_period)
                                        |(Cust_table_repayment.yearly==time_period)
                                    )].groupby(['Customer', 'Product', 'City', 'Month']).Amount.sum().reset_index().sort_values('Amount', ascending=False).head(10)

# another way
def top10Customers2(prod_cat, time_period):
    selected_df = Cust_table_repayment.loc[(Cust_table_repayment['Product'].str.lower()==prod_cat) 
                                           & ((Cust_table_repayment.monthly==time_period)
                                              |(Cust_table_repayment.yearly==time_period)
                                             )].copy()
    selected_df = selected_df.groupby(['Customer', 'Product', 'City', 'Month']).Amount.sum().reset_index()
    return selected_df.nlargest(10, 'Amount')
```